# Laravel Homestead composer errors

Tags: laravel, vagrant, composer-php

When I try to 'vagrant up' on a Homestead 5 box following the instructions on http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead ,I get the following error. I am behind a proxy, however I believe I have it setup correctly in the Vagrantfile.

I have not installed composer locally (as the instructions did not include this), is that something I need to do?

Is there a way to confirm this is not an issue with my proxy settings in Vagrantfile?

```
==> default:   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

==> default:   The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy

==> default:

==> default:

==> default:

==> default: self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [version]
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
```

Comment: i believe the problem because you are behind a proxy try to use a VPN connection

Comment: If you ssh on to your VM (`vagrant ssh`) what happens when you try `wget https://getcomposer.org/version`?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by also adding a line with homestead to the hosts-file in Windows:

```
[ip used in homestead.yaml] homestead
```

Hope this helps. It was easy to find similar questions, but difficult finding the answer.